# How to apply type check?

Tags: python

My task is to write a function named `only_ints` that takes two parameters. Your function should return `True` if both parameters are integers, and `False` otherwise.

For example, calling `only_ints(1, 2)` should return `True`, while calling `only_ints("a", 1)` should return `False`.

I'm confused. How do I apply `type()`? Because `isinstance(False, int)` outputs --> `True`

Answer (score 1):

`isinstance` is the right tool to be used here. `bool` is a private case of `int` and therefore we give him a special care :-)

Try (`print(True + 1)`) and see that the result is `2`

```
def only_ints(x: int, y:int) -> bool:
    return isinstance(x, int) and not isinstance(x, bool) and isinstance(y, int) and not isinstance(y, bool)

print(only_ints(4, 6))
print(only_ints(4, False))
```

output

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `==` to compare the `type` of a variable or value to a known type.

```
>>> type(True) == int
False
>>> type(3) == int
True
```

Before you implement `only_ints` using `type`, you should verify that you don't want `True` and `False` to be considered int. Booleans do evaluate to integer values in Python in many contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `type` and `==`. isinstance sadly does not behave intuitively in this situation.

```
def only_ints(x,y):
    return type(x) == int and type(y) == int
```